# Why don't integrals start at $-\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any specific reason for which integrals start at zero? Logically when we think of an integral as a summation of area, it must start from negative infinity right? Why do indefinite integrals start at zero? Like when I plug in a value in the indefinite integral, we get the area from 0 to the plugged in value. Therefore why not assume that they start from zero? If yes, then why, intuitively?

I think I'm confused with the idea of an indefinite integral. Please consider that I'm **self-teaching** Calculus and am sorry if I'm too silly but I suppose my doubts would be cleared if I'm made clear about the **Geometrical** (if it has any) and Mathematical meaning of an Indefinite Integral and why do we get finite values when substitute some values of x when we're told that they're indefinite and are of no meaning?

Comment: What do you mean "indefinite integrals start at zero"?

Comment: Integrals don't "start at $0$". They start wherever it makes sense in context. If you want the area under the graph of  a function whose domain is all of the real line, then the integral will "start" at $-\infty$.

Comment: That I know of, there is no such convention in either direction: you just write one or the other (or something else entriely) based on the needs of the discussion. Speaking of $\int_{-\infty}^x f(s)\,ds$ inherently needs some considerations along the lines of $\lim_{t\to-\infty} \int_t^x f(s)\,ds$ existing, which is not always the case even for very regular functions.

Comment: Integrals start from where you choose , not necessarily from $0$

Comment: I never thought of indefinite integrals starting or ending anywhere (that's what makes them indefinite).   I think of them, well, as the class of antiderivatives, although that is an oversimplification.

Comment: An indefinite integral always has a $+C$ constant - and two functions which differ by a constant are anti-derivatives of the same function. If you think of $F_1(x)=\int_{a}^x f(x)\,dx$ and $F_2(x)=\int_b^x f(x)dx,$ the are both valid indefinite integrals of $f$ because they differ by a real constant. But if, say $b=-\infty,$ $F_2$ might be infinite or undefined, and thus the difference might be infinite or not exist.

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable, we need to know what you think it means. Who told you that indefinite integrals start at zero? How did they tell you this?

Comment: Based on your recent edit, I guess nobody told you that indefinite integrals start at zero; rather, you looked at some examples of indefinite integrals and implicitly reinterpreted them as definite integrals with a zero at the "lower" bound. But that is just a guess. You might have more luck getting this question reopened if you led us through a more complete account of your reasoning from beginning to end. I'm betting there's a misapprehension in there somewhere, but it may take more information to flush it out.

Comment: For some $f$, e.g. polynomials, their commonly listed indefinite integral (without the $+C$) matches the definite integral from $0$:

$$\begin{align*}
\int x^n\ dx &= \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C;
& \frac{0^{n+1}}{n+1}&= 0
&&\implies &\int_0^x s^n\ ds &= \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{align*}$$

But not when the particular indefinite integral is non-zero at $0$:

$$\begin{align*}
\int \sin x\ dx &= -\cos x+C;
& -\cos\frac\pi2&= 0
&&\implies &\int_{\pi/2}^x \sin s\ ds &= -\cos x\\
\int e^x\ dx &= e^x+C;
&\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x&= 0
&&\implies &\int_{-\infty}^x e^s\ ds &= e^x\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: @Gonçalo Some of our best questions are based on false premises. We get to explain why the premises are false.

Comment: @DavidK, I maintain my vote.

Comment: "Some of our best questions are based on false premises." A strange point of view, I agree Goncalo.

Comment: @Peter I grant that "best" may be an exaggeration, but there are plenty of such questions. For example, someone posts a question that says, "I followed this procedure and got the wrong answer, what did I do wrong?" and the answer is, "You didn't do anything wrong, that's the correct answer and here's why," that's a question that was based on a false premise. If we can only respond to people who know exactly what they're talking about when they post, what does this site offer that MathOverflow doesn't?

Comment: The main problem I see with this question is not the false premises but the lack of useful information to help find the origin of the error. Finding out that the OP is self-learning is another clue.

Comment: "Indefinite integral" is a term that has a very precise mathematical meaning, nothing "indefinite" about it (except the constant of integration, if you want to consider that "indefinite"). It might help if we knew what material you were self-studying from, for example one of the MIT OCW classes or a textbook, and in particular which course and/or which textbook. Concrete examples help too, such as showing an actual integral and its solution and what then happens when you substitute a value for $x$. Remember that we have no other way to know what you've seen if you don't tell us.

Comment: @David K Really thanks for being so concerned with my question. My original confusion is whether indefinite integrals measure area under the graph and if they do, why do the start at a specific point? Like the indefinite integral of $2x$ starts measuring area from 0 as it is evaluated as $\frac{x^2}{2}$. The book I refer to is "Calculus Made Easy" by Silvanus P. Thompson. I've also posted another question regarding this and this is the link for the same https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4887981/1170922

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have come to a conclusion about indefinite integrals by extrapolating from a sample of observations that was too small.

There's another fundamental issue here: when you learned about the indefinite integral of a function, what were you told it is?

**An indefinite integral is not a summation of area.**

There's nothing wrong with using a summation of area (with appropriate modifications for such things as functions with negative values) to explain *definite* integrals.
There's at least one calculus textbook that defines the definite integral this way even before defining differentiation.

For the *indefinite* integral, however, a better basis for a definition is:

[What function do we differentiate to get the function $f(x)$?](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/indefiniteintegrals.aspx)

There's no area summation involved here, only differentiation.

For example, you might find the following solution of an indefinite integral in a textbook:

$$ \int \frac x{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\, \mathrm dx = \sqrt{x^2 + 1} + C. $$

If you set $C=0$, which is what I think you were implicitly doing in the examples of integrals you looked at, you might say the integral is $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.
But
$$ \int_0^x \frac t{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}}\, \mathrm dt \neq \sqrt{x^2 + 1}. $$

That is, $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ is never the area under the graph of
$\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$ from $0$ to $x$.

But it's even worse than that. There is **nothing** you can replace the $0$ with that will turn this inequality into an equation for even one single value of $x$.
You can't use $-\infty$ because the integral would be undefined then
(too much area), and if you choose any other constant $a$ you get

$$ \int_a^x \frac t{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}}\, \mathrm dt = \sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt{a^2 + 1}, $$

and this will never equal $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ because $\sqrt{a^2 + 1}$ is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been mostly answered in comments,
which I have tried to organize here.

> Like when I plug in a value in the indefinite integral, we get the area from 0 to the plugged in value.

If we forget that every indefinite integral includes a $+C$ term, or if we suppose that $C=0$, we *sometimes* get the area from $0$ to the plugged-in value.

For example:
\begin{align}
\int x \,\mathrm dx &= \frac12 x^2 + C, \\
\int_0^x t \,\mathrm dt &= \frac12 x^2. \\
\end{align}

But sometimes we don't get that result:
\begin{align}
\int \sin x \,\mathrm dx &= -\cos x + C, \\
\int_0^x \sin t \,\mathrm dt &= 1 - \cos x \neq -\cos x.
\end{align}

In the following example, the indefinite integral actually **does** match the definite integral from $-\infty$ if you set $C=0$ in the usual formula:
\begin{align}
\int e^x \,\mathrm dx &= e^x + C, \\
\int_{-\infty}^x e^t \,\mathrm dt &= e^x. \\
\end{align}

So a simple answer is that when you've seen enough different integrals, the premise of the question won't appear to be true anymore.

In addition, if we **did** try to define every indefinite integral by taking the area of the curve from $-\infty$ to $x$, how would we evaluate the integral of $x^2$?

$$ \int_{-\infty}^x t^2\,\mathrm dt = ? $$

There is an infinite amount of area under the graph of $y=x^2$ from $-\infty$ to any finite value of $x$.